# SQL row/record automatically deleted upon insertion, how come?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm on an MS SQL Server 2008 R2 server (on Amazon AWS server) and I have a table with ID and other columns (columnX and columnY) with a certain database. Upon insertion of several rows of data, row(s) with columnY of value "aParticularValue" would be automatically deleted.  How do I know?  Certain rows with certain IDs are missing, IDs sequential.  I've checked this table does not have trigger, which might have caused this problem.  And I don't have any process which would perform such an action.  Where may I look for its culprit?  Thanks.

Comment: Is your ID an identity? It might have been caused by, for example, failed inserts (where the current identity of the table will increase but no data will be inserted). Are you sure it only happens when a particular value is inserted into column Y? If so, have you tested it to see if there's an error?

Comment: @ZLK, one of the values attempted to be inserted exceeded the defined space/length for that column, oddly, SQL didn't complained as it usually does, thus.  I missed it.  Fixed now.  Also, yes, the ID column is of identity incremental, I wish data insertion failed sql server would roll back, thus, we clearly know that data failed to be inserted. Thanks